# Tensorflow: Resize list of images of different sizes

Tags: python, tensorflow

I created a list of images `L` which contains images of different size:

```
L = 
(1, 333, 500, 3)
(1, 500, 333, 3)
(1, 257, 296, 3)
```

The data type of these images is `np.uint8`.

My goal is to pass these images to a function `process_images()` that reshapes the images to a predefined size `size = [100,100]` and returns the following list

```
L_new = 
(1, 100, 100, 3)
(1, 100, 100, 3)
(1, 100, 100, 3)
```

or a numpy-array of size `[3,100,100,3]`.

The function that processes the images is defined below:

```
def process_images(X):
    X = tf.convert_to_tensor(X, dtype=tf.uint8)
    X = tf.image.resize_images(X, size=[100,100])
    return X
```

So far I get an error if I  call `img=sess.run(process_images(L))`:

`TypeError: Expected uint8, got array([[[[  0,  91, 127],
         [ 17,  94, 122],
         [ 39,  90,  85],
         ...,
         [ 67, 128,  87],
         [ 71, 129,  88],
         [ 71, 130,  86]]]], dtype=uint8) of type 'ndarray' instead.'`

What do I do wrong?

Comment: what kind of error?

Comment: Could you use skimage library? For example: `images_100 = np.array([skimage.transform.resize(image, (100, 100)) for image in images])`

Comment: @iGian I would like to use Tensorflow.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @AndreyKiteGorin I updated my question and added the error message.

Comment: are you sure that the convert_to_tensor accepts multiple images as input? I think you need a look for this with this method or every single image...

Answer (score 0):

I changed the answer since i missed some points in the description of the problem. Here is the correct answer:

```
def process_image(x):
    x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=tf.uint8)
    return tf.image.resize_images(x, size=[100,100])

def process_list(X):
    L = [process_image(x) for x in X]
    return tf.stack(L, axis=0)

import matplotlib.image as mpimg

imgs=[mpimg.imread('nadine.jpg'), mpimg.imread('andy.jpg')]
shapes= [img.shape for img in imgs]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    imgs1=sess.run(process_list(imgs))


print(shapes)
print(imgs1.shape)
```

here are the shapes of initial arrays and final result

```
[(1077, 1280, 3), (2946, 3930, 3)]
(2, 100, 100, 3)
```

The point is that you can't convert list of arrays of different shapes into tensor by `tf.convert_to_tensor`. You need to do the conversion one by one for each array and then stack the resulting tensors together.

Comment: Does that also work if `img` is a list with images of different sizes?

Comment: you need to pass images one by one into the function in this case, coz you can only define tf tensor with fixed shape. You function is expecting tensor, so you'll have to construct one in some way